# Migrating Runs to MLFlow 0.9

Tags: mlflow

we have been using MLFlow 0.8.2 (with a local file store) for a while, and I was happy to see the release of MLFlow 0.9. After upgrading to the new version, I realized that pointing the MLFLow server to the old file store leads to a non-working web UI (I just see some image of a waterfall).

Is there a recommendation for proper migration of data when upgrading?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Da